# Broadcast Receiver onReceive getting called twice when detecting incoming calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I only used a single class in my project which is extending broadcast receiver (Only to check if it's getting called twice). There is no other class file. So there is no question of calling it multiple times from somewhere else. I have declared it in manifest like below -

Manifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.contactlistview"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            <receiver android:name=".Detection" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />


            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Detection.java

```
public class Detection extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.i("Called", "OnReciver");
        Toast.makeText(context, "incoming", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Log Output -

```
08-24 14:50:21.707: I/Called(21758): OnReciver
08-24 14:50:32.648: I/Called(21758): OnReciver
```

Once it is being called when the call connects and once when the call is terminated( I came to conclusion by noting the time stamp )
Is it normal behaviour of broadcast receiver when detecting incoming calls ? It will be called twice always ? or i am missing something?

Comment: Have you tried reading the extras from the intent. `EXTRA_STATE`. See if they are the same as well

Comment: i have tried that too in the other project where it was getting called twice. So just to understand why its getting called multiple times. I created a new project containing only broadcast receiver and result is same

Comment: There are 9 seconds difference between those two logcat entries. You're monitoring for phone 'state' which could be several different things - each time the 'state' changes your receiver will be notified.

Comment: Thanks hoomi and @Squonk , I understood the reason now.

Answer (score 0):

onReceive is getting called twiced because:

> 1. When the phone rings: EXTRA_STATE_RINGING
> 2. When the phone is idle after finishing ringing: EXTRA_STATE_IDLE

If you want to perform some operation only when phone rings then you have to do this inside onReceive:

```
String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

if(state=TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)[
//do something here
}
```